# Make Label Forecolor light transparent C#

Tags: c#, winforms, label, opacity

I have a label in front of a black form.
My `lable1` ForeColor is red, but I want the label slightly transparent.
100% you see the label full > 0% you can't see the label, and I want the opacity by about 50%?

I have no clue how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: To clear things up, you need a translucent Label (the whole Control, with a degree of opacity) or just it's Text?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Color transparentColour = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red);
label1.BackColor = transparentColour;
```

The `Color.FromArgb(x, y)` allows you to set colour `y` with opacity `x/255`

Comment: shouldn't it be 128, Color.Red?

Comment: Doh! Yes, you're quite right. Am I right about `x/255` or should it be `x/256` - i think 255 because you can have 0...